# How to implement bidirectional encoder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, encoder, bidirectional

In Tensorflow, all the encoder-decoder functions (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py) use a unidirectional implementation of RNN unit.

How can we implement the bidirectional encoder (http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473 or alike systems) in Tensorflow so that both forward and backward sequence can be simultaneously learnt in encoder-decoder setting?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very easy. You can just encode a sequence normally from the first to the last, and get the states and last output as the output; and then reverse the sequence and apply the same process and you get the same amount of states and output. You concatenate each state-pair from the same item and then you get the combined states and two outputs.

You can just use the API in TensorFlow: [bidirectional_dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn). Plus, [this](https://github.com/hycis/bidirectional_RNN) is the implementation in Theano.